# Single Stationary point in: $x' = ax^2 + bx + c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Imagine you have the following differential equation:
$$
x' = ax^2 + bx + c
$$
And you wanted to impose that the solution only has one stationary point. Finding the stationary points:
$$
x' = 0 
$$
If we want only one solution, we have:
$$
\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} = 0
$$
Factoring the expression:
$$
x' = a \left( x + \sqrt{\frac{c}{a}} \right)^2
$$
Now, if we want that our solution to be stable, we have:
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = k, k \in \mathbb{R}
$$
$$ 
x'(t) < 0
$$
Imposing this restrictions:
$$
x'(t) = a \left( x + \sqrt{\frac{c}{a}} \right)^2 < 0 \Rightarrow a < 0
$$
and because, we cannot have negative signs values inside the square root, we have:
$$
c < 0
$$
Is this correct? Did I make any mistake? I don't know exactly if this is a good procedure for this specific problem.

Comment: The case that you explore is semi-stable. For stability you need a root with odd multiplicity.